# It does not give an error but it does not insert in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have this form and script on a page:

```
<section class="hide-section" id="produto_1"> 
<form class="form-validate" id="feedback_form">
    <div class="campo">
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        </div>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required="" style="width:350px">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" style="width:160px" required="" size="120">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn_contact" type="button">Registo</button>
</form>
</section> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(".btn_contact").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./inserir",
                    data: $("#feedback_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        if ($.trim(data) == 'true') {
                            $("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
                           dataType: "json",
                            $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
                        } else {
                            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
</script>
```

On the insert page I have this php code:

```
$name = isset($_POST["DescricaoProd"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoProd"] : '';
$unid = isset($_POST["DescricaoUnid"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoUnid"] : '';

if (!empty($name) && !empty($unid)) {  
   echo json_encode("true");
} else {
    echo json_encode("false");
}

$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "nome_DB");

$sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";
if ($conn->query($sql)) { // check for === TRUE is not necessary
   // either put the second query in here, or just enjoy the success
} else {
   // get the error, throw a message...
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM StockHigieneteste");

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
} else {
    // get the error, throw a message...
}
$conn->close();
```

The code was working correctly, like inserting it into the database table, but now it was checking the part of cleaning the inputs and is not already inserting into the database table, but it also does not give any errors in the console. Can anyone help identify the problem?

When I put in the beginning of the code this part:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

False message appears, so it no longer changes to insert, should be true.

If you do:

```
var_dump ($name);
var_dump ($unid);
```

returns this:

> string(0) "" string(0) "" "false"

Variables are not receiving value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171733/discussion-between-jaydp-and-iniciante).

Answer (score 1):

Please use wordpress standard AJAX

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );
function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_localize_script( 'my_voter_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my_voter_script' );

}

add_action("wp_ajax_custom_function", "my_custom_function");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_function", "my_custom_function");

function my_custom_function()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $name = isset($_POST["DescricaoProd"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoProd"] : '';
    $unid = isset($_POST["DescricaoUnid"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoUnid"] : '';

    if (!empty($name) && !empty($unid)) {  
        echo json_encode("true");
    } else {
        echo json_encode("false");
    }

    $mydb = new wpdb('USUARIO','SENHA','nome_DB','localhost');
    $rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");

    $mydb->insert( 
        'ProdHigieneteste', 
        array( 
            'DescricaoProd' => $name, 
            'DescricaoUnid' => $unid 
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s', 
            '%d' 
        ) 
    );

    $mydb->insert( 
        'StockHigieneteste', 
        array( 
            'DescricaoProd' => $name, 
            'DescricaoUnid' => $unid 
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s', 
            '%d' 
        ) 
    );

    /* If you want to use regular wordpress db then use $wpdb */

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM StockHigieneteste");
wp_die();
}
```

In ajax change URL parameter with "`url : myAjax.ajaxurl,`"

While putting "`wp_localize_script`" use your custom js slug which you have included

Comment: But I did not include my custom js slug, can you help include it?

Comment: use ===  'url' :  '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ).'?action=custom_function'?>'  === code in your ajax for URL set

Comment: I'm not realizing where I have to use this part of the code `use === 'url': '<? Php echo admin_url (' admin-ajax.php ').'? Action = custom_function '?>' === = custom_function '?>' === `, can you edit the ask and put that part of the code?

Comment: in you ajax function where you declare 'url' parameter  url: "./inserir",

Comment: remove that line its sample query for get results from database. 
you can use your own query if you want else remove it

Comment: use wp_die() at the end of ajax fuction

Comment: Where you have put that ajax action and function which I share in this answer?

Comment: have you put that code in functions.php OR any other place?

Comment: I am thinking you are confused about how to use wordpress ajax.

Please add above code in answer in functions.php.